# How to make a stone (or something similar) and put there electronics?

Tags: material-selection, stones

I'm an electronics hobbyist. I'd like to put a Wi-Fi module in my garden. It would be awesome if it would be possible to put that electronics into a stone or something similar. It doesn't need to be able to open.

**Things I considered:**

**1.** There's a rock for hiding keys available on the market:
[image: http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/jrsAAOSwPh5ZIqe7/s-l1600.jpg]

The seller says that it's made of synthetic resin. But I'm not sure how to make that in home conditions? This specific product is too small. I'd require something a little bit bigger.

**2.**

> You might just take a watertight hobby box and an adhesive, perhaps like the foam used by pond hobbyists, and 'glue' rocks over the box. – user2448131

IMHO that wouldn't be ideal enough? I mean you could easily see that it's just a bunch of stones that are glued, right? I think I'm looking for something more plain/consistent.

The idea is good in general but this time I'm looking for something that would cover it from every angle. Such a whim.

So, how to make such a thing like the box for hiding a key or something similar easily at home/garage workshop conditions?

Comment: Mold making kits are available in most art supply stores. Look up smooth on products https://www.smooth-on.com/.

Comment: I am not tech savvy.  Can you do a thin layer of concrete & have it operate?  You can carve styrofoam to shape, and then cover it with concrete and then paint it & have it look very realistic.  I'd personally think you would need to make your rock with a compartment & place the electronics into something waterproof that sits under the rock.  But the rock making portion isn't hard.  It can easily be done by a novice with patience.

Comment: Resin plus stone dust can make fake rocks, but stone dust isn't easy to obtain in quantity.  Hollowing out a (fairly soft) rock with power tools might be a better option.  Another source of bits is garden lighting made to look like rocks.

Comment: I like the idea, but don't forget to allow some way for the electronics to cool. A wifi access point sealed inside something air tight, and with some thermal insulation, such as you're considering, will overheat and either "age" a lot faster than normal, or just plain die. The antenna could be another problem.

Answer (score 2):

What about Feather Rock? That is lightweight and easy to alter. Or check out some of the hidden outdoor speaker ideas and simply convert them for your project.

Comment: I think Feather Rock is a brand yes? Pumice would be the generic term for what you are suggesting.

Comment: Not sure if it is a brand or not. Just know that is what I have heard it called everywhere. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Marble and sandstone are two soft natural stone (like) materials.  Both can be easily drilled and filed to create a hidden compartment or pocket.  The pocket can then be closed and even made water resistant by molding a hatch cover from any number of materials available at lowes or home depot.

A natural stone will not cause scrutiny from a discerning eye.